# What information can I get using Social Media APIs for analytics purpose?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, analytics, instagram-api, social-networking

I am working on website analytics tool. I have to show social media information (useful data for analytics) such as profile, mentions etc.

I am able to get Twitter profile and mentions using twitter API (without user authentication). I want similar data from other social media APIs such as Facebook, LinkedIn, Instagram, Google+, Pinterest and so on. I want to read public data (as I am doing with twitter) without user permission.

Comment: _“I want similar data from other social media APIs such as Facebook, LinkedIn, Instagram, Google+, Pinterest and so on.”_ - then I suggest you go start reading the API documentations of Facebook, LinkedIn, Instagram, Google+, Pinterest and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain most of a Facebook user's information if the user explicitly grants your app permission to do so. The Facebook Graph API explorer is a good place to start: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/